# HK2 named Optional constant parameter

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, hk2

We use HK2 as our dependency injection framework via dropwizard, hence jersey 2.0. With the dropwizard 2.0 upgrade, it seems there is a new feature for [Optional parameters](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-hk2/issues/457).

This broke usage of our injection of various configuration Strings, some optional, some not.

```
bind(configuration.getFilesLocation()).to(String.class).named("filesLocation");
bind(configuration.getGeoIpPath()).to(new TypeLiteral<Optional<String>>() {
                                }).named("geoIpPath");
...
public GeoIpUtil(@Named("geoIpPath") Optional<String> geoIpPath) {
```

So, this used to work for us. But now, with the Optional change, if `configuration.getGeoIpPath()` is `Optional.empty()`, then the `GeoIpUtil` class gets `configuration.getFilesLocation()` value. So, it looks like when the named injection cannot be found, HK2 injects any `String` binding. So even if I change the code to *the right way*

```
    if (configuration.getGeoIpPath().isPresent()) {
       bind(configuration.getGeoIpPath().get()).to(String.class).named("geoIpPath");
    }
```

HK2 will still inject the `filesLocation`.

Is there any way I can solve this without introducing new classes or passing the whole `configuration` object? Perhaps a way to make HK2 strictly check the named binding?

I tried injecting `null` to `String.class`, but the call crashed immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The following is working for me, if I missed some setup that you have, please let me know:

```
@Classes({ MyTest.GeoIpUtil.class })
public class MyTest extends HK2Runner {

    // @Inject (Inject manually)
    private GeoIpUtil sut;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(sut != null && !sut.geoIpPath.isPresent());
        assertTrue(sut != null && sut.geoIpPath2.isPresent() && sut.geoIpPath2.get().equals("geoIpPath"));
    }

    @Override
    public void before() {
        super.before();

        final String filesLocation = "filesLocation";
        final Optional<String> geoIpPath = Optional.empty();
        final Optional<String> geoIpPath2 = Optional.of("geoIpPath");

        ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(testLocator, new AbstractBinder() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(filesLocation).to(String.class).named("filesLocation");
                bind(geoIpPath).to(new TypeLiteral<Optional<String>>() {}).named("geoIpPath");
                bind(geoIpPath2).to(new TypeLiteral<Optional<String>>() {}).named("geoIpPath2");
            }
        });

        sut = testLocator.getService(GeoIpUtil.class);
    }

    @Service
    public static class GeoIpUtil {

        private final Optional<String> geoIpPath;
        private final Optional<String> geoIpPath2;

        @Inject
        public GeoIpUtil(@Named("geoIpPath") final Optional<String> geoIpPath, @Named("geoIpPath2") final Optional<String> geoIpPath2) {
            this.geoIpPath = geoIpPath;
            this.geoIpPath2 = geoIpPath2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't really tried to isolate the problem with a minimum test unfortunately. The whole hk2 setup comes from dropwizard 2.0 (hk2 2.6.1) which may not be the vanilla setup. We do multiple `ServiceLocatorUti.bind()` calls in various places. And probably some other adjustments. I'm afraid there are too many variables here and considering I have already done a workaround with a custom `Optional` class of my own, I think digging into this will take a very long time.

Comment: Ok, seems strange though that it would inject just any String, for me HK2 throws an exception if the named service cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there seemed to be some bugs in the Optional injection feature of hk2, which were fixed here https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish-hk2/pull/516 and should be part of future releases